# How to pop up a dialog to confirm delete when user long press on the list item?

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog, delete-row

I am learning from a online tutorial, and i try to implement some function by my own.
How can i pop up a dialog to alert user when detect a long press on  list item? Following is some code from that tutorial:

```
public class FriendList extends ListActivity 
{


private static final int ADD_NEW_FRIEND_ID = Menu.FIRST;

private static final int EXIT_APP_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;
private IAppManager imService = null;
private FriendListAdapter friendAdapter;

public String ownusername = new String();

private class FriendListAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{       
    class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
        ImageView icon;
    }
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Bitmap mOnlineIcon;
    private Bitmap mOfflineIcon;        

    private FriendInfo[] friends = null;


    public FriendListAdapter(Context context) { // Constructor of Class "FriendListAdapter"
        super();            

        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        mOnlineIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.greenstar);
        mOfflineIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.redstar);

    }

    public void setFriendList(FriendInfo[] friends)
    {
        this.friends = friends;
    }


    public int getCount() {  // get how many row are in the listview

        return friends.length;
    }


    public FriendInfo getItem(int position) { // get item from the row

        return friends[position];
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { // For modify the content of row
        // A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid unneccessary calls
        // to findViewById() on each row.
        ViewHolder holder;

        // When convertView is not null, we can reuse it directly, there is no need
        // to reinflate it. We only inflate a new View when the convertView supplied
        // by ListView is null.
        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.friend_list_screen, null);

            // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children views
            // we want to bind data to.
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);                                       

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }   
        else {
            // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
            // and the ImageView.
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // Bind the data efficiently with the holder.
        holder.text.setText(friends[position].userName);
        holder.icon.setImageBitmap(friends[position].status == STATUS.ONLINE ? mOnlineIcon : mOfflineIcon);

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: you should use context menu for that ...register your list item for context menu

Comment: I think that you are trying to do a thing much more complicated than you can. You should start with the training section an the android developers site.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

use the code as :

```
this.getListView().setLongClickable(true);
 this.getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    //Do your tasks here


            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    Activity.this);
            alert.setTitle("Alert!!");
            alert.setMessage("Are you sure to delete record");
            alert.setPositiveButton("YES", new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                               //do your work here                      
                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            });
            alert.setNegativeButton("NO", new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            alert.show();

    return true;
  }
  });
```

You can customize alert dialog according to your need...

Answer (score 0):

Hope it's help:

```
 selectRoom.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int position, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Dialog();
 }
}
```

or

```
final MyDialog rDialog=new MyDialog(this,this);
        return false;
    }

} );

public void Dialog()    {

    AlertDialog.Builder dialogAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    dialogAlert.setTitle("Demo ?");

    dialogAlert.show();
}

 //Another way

 public class MyDialog extends Dialog {

Activity act;
public ReminderSettingDialog(Context context,Activity act) {
super(context);
this.act=act;
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.settings);

}
}
```